# Get div text with xpath, including link text

Tags: html, xpath

What is the xpath selector for getting a Tweet div's full text as one return value, including link text?

```
//*[contains(@class, 'tweet-text')][2]/text()
```

The above works ok for divs without links, but when the tweet contains links it just returns the first string segment.

Comment: can you share the url you are testing? please update your question with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The above works ok for divs without links, but when the tweet contains links it just returns the first string segment.

This is because of that `/text()` part - you are basically matching the *top-level text children nodes only*. To match all the text nodes inside the element, at any level, you can do:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'tweet-text')][2]//text()
```

This is though usually automatically done by HTML parsers when asking for the "text" value of the node - they go to all the children nodes recursively and get the "text" values - then, join them.

Demonstrating everything mentioned above using Python+[`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) parser:

```
In [1]: from lxml.html import fromstring 

In [2]: html = """
    ...: <div>
    ...:     div text here
    ...:     <a href="https://google.com">link text</a>
    ...: </div>"""

In [3]: root = fromstring(html)

In [4]: root.xpath('//div/text()')  # <- No text of the a element
Out[4]: ['\n    div text here\n    ', '\n']

In [5]: root.xpath('//div//text()')  # <- We've got all the texts now
Out[5]: ['\n    div text here\n    ', 'link text', '\n']

In [6]: root.xpath("//div")[0].text_content()  # <- but this would that for us
Out[6]: '\n    div text here\n    link text\n'
```